# HERE Maps Tile API returns CORS Errors at Random

Tags: here-api

Few requests to Here Map API returns 200 response but most of requests are blocked due to CORS and returns 301 response.

**Error Message in browser console:** Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://2.base.maps.cit.api.here.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/24c3a120e9/normal.day/10/840/607/256/png8?xxxxxxxx' from origin 'http://google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**200 Response:**
[image]

**301 Response:**
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by removing the "CIT" from the request.
Regards.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).